# How to change value in java properties file using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, properties

I have java project with resource directory and project.properties file inside. Some of the property values have to be set as argument while building project with Gradle. Could someone suggest me the way I can do it right.

Comment: You can pass them with `-P` switch.

Answer (score 0):

One way to modify a property file before it is packaged into a jar would be to extend the `processResources` task:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

processResources {
  filesMatching('*.properties') {
    filter( ReplaceTokens, tokens:['DB_URL' : dev_system_db_url,])
  }
}
```

The value in the property file should be set to `@DB_URL@`

You can define `dev_system_db_url` in `gradle.properties` or modify it on the command line `gradlew build -Pdev_system_db_url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname`

I prefer tokens because they inform others when editing the property file that the value will be modified by the build.